# Why are these the subset of $\Omega \notin \mathcal F$(sigma-field )

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\Omega = [0,\infty)$,be a sample space and let $\mathcal F$ be the sigma-field of subsets of $\Omega$ generated by all sets of the form $(n,n+1)$,for $n=0,...,\infty$.Are the following subsets of $\Omega$ in $\mathcal F$ ?

Why is

1.$[0,k]$ for any positive integer $k$ ,$\notin$ $\mathcal F$

2.${k}$ for any positive integer $k$ ,$\notin$ $\mathcal F$

I think $[0,k]$ and ${k}$ for any positive interger k are in the $\Omega$ this sample  space,why are 1. and 2. $\notin$ $\mathcal F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A_1,A_2,...$ is a disjoint sequence of sets in a set $\Omega$ then the sigma field generated by these sets is simply the collection of all sets that can be expressed as unions of the sets $A_0,A_1,A_2,...$ where $A_0=\Omega \setminus \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$. This can be proved by verifying that the collection of such unions is actually a sigma field. [ The complement of such a union is the union of the remaining $A_k$'s]. Thus, we know exactly what the sets in your sigma field are. Can you now prove 1) and 2)? Hint: if a set in this sigma field contains one integer it contains all!

Comment: i don't understand your explanation,can you explain easier ?

Comment: If $\{B_1,B_2,...\}$ is a partition of $\Omega$ then the collection of all possible  unions of these forms a sigma algebra and it is the smallest sigma algebra containing each of the sets $B_k$. In out case we only have a disjoint sequence; the union  of the intervals $(n,n+1)$ does not cover the entire space. That is why I had to first write down $A_0$ (the complement of the union of $A_K:k\geq 1$). Once you know what exactly are the sets in the sigma algbra it becomes easy to see that the given sets do not belong to it.

Comment: By a partition I mean a disjoint collection of sets whose union is the whole space.

Comment: What is this mean? $A_0=\Omega ∖
∪^∞_{k=1}A_k$